# Displaying Python database on Flask web server

Tags: database, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working on a project that requires that I create a create a database, import data into it, and display it on a FLASK local server. I've created the database, but I'm confused as to what I need to do in order to display its tables on the server. I have it set up to display information via HTML through render_template and believe I've established a connection via config.py, but I'm not sure where to go from here. I've read the following guides, but I don't quite understand them. If anybody could assist, I would appreciate it.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/sqlalchemy/
http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/config/

Below are the relevant files in the project root.

```
/project
    config.py
    database_insert.py
    server.py
    /app
        /templates
            index.html
        __init__.py
        models.py
        routes.py
```

config.py

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

class Config(object):
    SECRET_KEY = 'you-will-never-guess'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////project/app.db'
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
```

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

from app import routes, models
```

models.py

```
from app import db

class Lot(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    spots = db.relationship('Spot', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Lot {}>'.format(self.username)  

class Spot(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    availability = db.Column(db.String(140))
    spot_num = db.Column(db.String(140))
    lot_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('lot.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Spot {}>'.format(self.body)
```

routes.py

```
from app import app
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    lot_details = {
        'id': 'TEST_ID', #placeholder for testing purposes
        'title': 'TEST_TITLE' #placeholder for testing purposes
    }
    return render_template('index.html', lot=lot_details)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello, World!</p>
        <p>{{lot.id}}</p>
        <p>{{lot.title}}</p>
    </body>
```

Comment: Also, please take a look at your `__repr__` methods. Fields used to format returned value seems not right.

Answer (score 0):

At first, define helper method in your `Spot` model class.

```
class Spot(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    availability = db.Column(db.String(140))
    spot_num = db.Column(db.String(140))
    lot_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('lot.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Spot {}>'.format(self.body)

    def dump(self):
        return dict(id=self.id, title=self.title)
```

Then, in your flask route, you may query:

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    lot_details = Lot.query.first().dump() # query first item
    return render_template('index.html', lot=lot_details)
```

Comment: This returns an error because Lot is not defined in routes. When I try to define it, it returns another error that the database is inaccessible.

Comment: Are you importing it like this: `from models import Lot`?

Comment: I used `from app.models import Lot`and doing so returns `sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file`. When I used `from models import Lot`, it could not find the module models.

Comment: Stay with the first one, also replace `sqlite:////project/app.db` in `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` with `sqlite:///project/app.db`